# API platform Symfony 5 JWT acces control

Tags: api, rest, symfony, jwt, api-platform.com

I started an REST API with api platform using jwt token.
The main purpose is to register and login a user.
I tried to grant acces for non authenticated users to the post route
`api/users`
but something wrong with the following output:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

However the get route work without any Authorization bearer.

Here is my security.yaml

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                username_path: username
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I juste change my model annotations :

```
collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"}
 *     }
```

to

```
collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post"={"method"="POST", "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === false"}
 *     }
```